# Makefile for a simple Debian Repo

Tags: debian, make, dpkg

I'm making a very basic Debian repo for a client. Started with a bash script, but decided a Makefile would eliminate duplicated work. I've hammered out a working Makefile, but it works only if I `make all`. For some reason, a straight `make` only builds the first deb. `make clean` does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
MFGR:=MyCoolEmployer
MAJOR:=1
MINOR:=0
REVISION:=1000
VERSION:=$(MAJOR).$(MINOR)-$(REVISION)
MODELS:=SpiffyModel1 SpiffyModel2
COMMON:=common
SOFT_TARGETS:=$(COMMON) $(MODELS)
SOFT_TARGET_FOLDERS:=$(patsubst %, $(MFGR)-%_$(VERSION), $(SOFT_TARGETS))
DEBs := $(patsubst %, %.deb, $(SOFT_TARGET_FOLDERS))
REPO_DEBs :=$(patsubst %, Repo/binary/%, $(DEBs))
REPO=repo.zip
PACKAGES_GZ := Repo/binary/Packages.gz

%.deb: %
    dpkg-deb --build $<

$(REPO_DEBs): $(DEBs)
    cp $^ Repo/binary/

$(PACKAGES_GZ): $(REPO_DEBs)
    dpkg-scanpackages Repo/binary /dev/null | gzip -9c > $@

$(REPO): $(REPO_DEBs) $(PACKAGES_GZ)
    cd Repo; zip -r -v -0 ../$@ . ; cd ..

TARGETS: $(REPO) $(PACKAGES_GZ) $(REPO_DEBs) $(DEBs)

all:    TARGETS

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS)
```

This assumes the packages exist as folders named MyCoolEmployer-*PACKAGENAME*_1.0-1000

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you do `make clean`?  Does it just go *directly* back to your shell prompt?  Does it pause a little?  Does it say anything?  Are you sure that your `rm` command begins with a tab and not a bunch of spaces?  If you add some innocuous command (like `date` or `ls`) immediately before or after the `rm`, do they run when you do `make clean`?

Comment: Next time, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/), probably as `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question contains its own answer. 
By default, `make` processes only the first entry in the `Makefile`. 
You need to put the "all" entry first.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: You can also do ".DEFAULT_GOAL := all". https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html

Answer (score 6):

The "make clean" does nothing because $(TARGETS) isn't a variable, you've never set it to any value.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question OP has.